# JS - If 1st function results in error keep attempting to execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on some js code for an extension and my original function is working fine there's no problem there but Im trying to add some more code so that if --

When my function executes, if it results in opening a pop up div with an id of #somediv and the word error anywhere inside it then it will keep executing the function until the resulting pop up div has no error text/class/or id- word anywhere in it.

Does that make sense? Im not sure how to word it, or where to start.

Basically something like

```
var finderror = "error";
var containerdivid = "somediv";

function DoSomethingFirst() { //some function }
DoSomethingFirst();

if (containerdivid[0].match(finderror) == finderror) {
DoSomethingFirst();
}
```

Comment: Since this is or a Chrome extension, it could be the case that some asynchronous JS execution is involved. This would require a different approach and should be mentioned in the question. (Just a heads-up...)

Answer (score 0):

If you want check the content of `containerdiv` you can use `querySelector` or `textContent`:

```
...
var containerdiv = document.querySelector('#' + containerdivid);
while (containerdiv.textContent.indexOf(finderror) !== -1) {
    DoSomethingFirst();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use a while statement

```
var finderror = "error";
var containerdivid = "somediv";

function DoSomethingFirst() { //some function }

while (containerdivid[0].match(finderror) == finderror) {
    DoSomethingFirst();
}
DoSomethingAfter();
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to work/help. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: The problem comes from your comparator: "containerdivid[0].match(finderror) == finderror". You are setting your finderror var as a string, and from the match() function, you are getting an array or a null value, so the comparation is never goiung to match